# How to view build log in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build

I want to view the build log for a C# solution, to try and figure out why I am getting a particular build error.  So I googled, and found this neat little solution on msdn:

> "The old HTML log output option is no longer available - we use the
>   command MSBuild logging instead. What you need to do is go to
>   Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run. At the bottom,
>   change the logging level from Normal to Detailed for either the output
>   window or log file."

So I went to this "Build and Run" window and changed the settings for the output window and re-built.  Only problem is, I am not seeing any more logging in the output window than I was before.
I just see the same 1 error and 13 warnings and 0 information messages.

Tried closing VS2010 and re-opening it, but the result is the same.

Can anyone point out what I'm missing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you still only see the same 1 error and 13 warnings and 0 information messages, are you maybe looking in he Error List window by chance?...changing the output logging won't affect that.

It gives you a more detailed output of what goes on while MSBuild is building the solution - e.g for a default console app if I set it to diagnostic I get around 1500 messages in the output window (debug, windows, output), whereas quiet gives 3.

If that doesn't help, it might be worth calling msbuild directly and specifying verbose (via a .net command prompt) - e.g.:
msbuild "myProj.csproj" /v:diag /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;LogFile="D:\MyBuild.log"